# How can I uninstall npm version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

My npm version is 8.11.0.

When I create react package, but it gives me a Warn.

How can I uninstall it?

Comment: `npm uninstall package-name`

Answer (score 2):

```
npm uninstall <package_name>
```

To uninstall an unscoped, global package on the command line, use the `uninstall` command with the `-g` flag:

```
npm uninstall -g <package_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Locally uninstall npm package:

To uninstall a package you have previously installed locally, run following from the project root folder (the folder that contains the node_modules folder):

```
npm uninstall <package-name>
```

**Note: This operation will also remove the reference in the `package.json` file.**

If the package was a development dependency, listed in the `devDependencies` of the `package.json` file, you must use the `-D` / `--save-dev` flag to remove it from the file:

```
npm uninstall -D <package-name>
```

#### Globally uninstall npm package:

If the package is installed globally, you need to add the `-g` / `--global` flag:

```
npm uninstall -g <package-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just write in your terminal

```
npm uninstall <package_name_which_you_want_to_uninstall>
```