# How do I uninstall NPM v10.0.0 from Amazon Linux 2 4.14.322-244.536.amzn2.x86_64?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9, amazon-linux-2

I recently tried to upgrade my node version from v16.20.2 to v18.7.1 by compiling from the source code. I have since given up on that idea and I'm just going to use packages compatible with Node v16.20.2 and npm-8.19.2-1.16.18.1.3.el7.x86_6 to be on the safe side. Now I want to remove the version of NPM leftover from all of this.

Now when I run npm -v, it gives me this.

`npm WARN cli npm v10.0.0 does not support Node.js v16.20.2. This version of npm supports the following node versions:` ^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/. 10.0.0`

I tried using the npm uninstall command
`npm uninstall v10.0.0`
that I was told to do at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74556129/how-can-i-uninstall-npm-version) but when I run npm -v afterwards, I get the same reponse as last time.

Is there any way to remove specific versions or downgrade NPM on Amazon Linux 2 devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (nvm) to easily manage Node versions on the instance.

```
# Install nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash

# Verify installation
command -v nvm

# Install your version of node
nvm install 18.7.1 

# Make it the default Node version
nvm alias default 18.7.1
```

With a new Node version properly installed, nvm should align npm as well.

Full installation instructions can be found in [the docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating).